# I am trying to upgrade from the command line my ubuntu to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, versions, archive, download-speed

I have gone thru all the steps but I can't seem to download some archives.  Unable to fetch some archives".  I have changed server, run --fix-missing   ..still won't download the "Plasma" archive.  I can ping and go to the website.  Stumped!

```
Err:1 us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 plasma-desktop-data all 4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1 Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] 
E: Failed to fetch us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/plasma-desktop/… Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] 
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am moving from 18.04 to 20.04 – Timothy Bird 2 hours ago
I have run `sudo apt update` but when I run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` I fail to get some of the packages. I have also switched servers, "Main" "US" added other mirrors, but only with the same result. –

Comment: Without showing us the error message, we cannot really help.  If we see the packages, and/or error messages, providing we know your release, we can use command line tools (or online tools too) to look to see if you have release issues, source issues etc.. but to start with we need the package names so we have detail to enter into our preferred search tool (eg. `rmadison` for me; or packages.ubuntu.com online)

Comment: What are "*all the steps?*"

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1345345/edit) and show me the output of `sudo apt update` (use copy/paste, not screenshots), or use `Synaptic` RELOAD and copy/paste the error messages. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 plasma-desktop-data all 4:5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/plasma-desktop/plasma-desktop-data_5.18.5-0ubuntu0.1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
I am moving from 18.04 to  20.04

Comment: I have run sudo apt update  but when I run  sudo apt dist-upgrade
I fail to get some of the packages.  I have also switched servers, "Main"   "US"  added other mirrors, but only with the same result.

Comment: You didn't do as I asked. You didn't start comments to me with @heynnema so I missed them. You didn't show me the entire output. Please redo `sudo apt update` and copy/paste the entire output as an edit to your question... not in the comments please.